# Calculate curvature coefficient

Tags: r

In a linear distribution the slope coefficient indicates how steeply the distribution rises or falls. If I have a distribution that is **not linear but curved**, is there a similar metric indicating the overall rising or falling trend of the distribution?

Research on the internet suggests that such a metric exists: it is called the curvature coefficient or the second derivative of the distribution.

Let's say I have this distribution:

```
data <- c(1, 1.5, 2, 1.7, 2, 2.1, 3, 5, 9, 15)
```

How can I calculate in R the curvature coefficient?
I've been trying out using the `deriv` function but haven't been able to make it work. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `mean(diff(data, differences = 2))` is the average "acceleration" of the data, the 2nd derivative, the rate of change of its slope, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this. But to what extent is the value thus obtained indicative of whether, overall, the distribution trends upwards or downwards?

Comment: Upward or downwards would be captured by slope (aka derivative) alone. It sounded like you wanted to capture how much the slope is increasing, ie the 2nd derivative or the curvature.